# Can't find v, r & s values in the signed transaction of myetherwallet

Tags: myetherwallet, ecdsa

I tried to create a simple transaction using myetherwallet by importing my account from metamask. Once I've put the 'to' address, ether value and gas price, I clicked on 'generate transaction' which provided me with 'raw transaction' and 'signed transaction'. I however do not find the v,r,s values in the signed transaction, neither the tx hash. Shouldn't the signed transaction contain the signature? What am I missing here? 
[image]

Comment: Could you show your transactions?

Comment: the content of my signed transaction is this:
{"from":"0x4dbacd4235e071b023db285b40ada9ee3fbe19ba","gas":"0x5208","nonce":"0x00","gasPrice":"0x0826299e00","gasLimit":"0x5208","to":"0x5ACe430fef51fcAAa3E82AC9C27A016F1a68711f","value":"0x11c37937e08000","data":"0x","chainId":1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. Here's the answer:

In Myetherwallet, the signed transaction will keep showing in human readable form (and not bytes) till one uses his keystore or metamask wallet to actually complete the signing process. This step happens just after the 'generate transaction' when you press on Send Transaction. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The signed transaction contains v, r and s but they are [RLP encoded](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP).

The hash is the result of applying keccak256 to the signed transaction as binary string.